# Invoke function in shinyServer using reactive

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I have a shiny app which calls an external function based on user input. This function updates a data frame based on the input so it can be used to render a plot.

**getData function()**

```
getData= function(inpName)
{
   // a piece of code based on inpName
}
```

**shinyUI.R**

```
library(shiny)
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("title"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      textInput("name","Enter a name")),
    mainPanel())
))
```

**shinyServer.R**

```
library(shiny)
shinyServer(function(input,output)
  {
  getData=reactive({getData(input$name) })
})
```

No matter what I try I just can't seem to get the shinyServer to call the function and update a df. Could someone advise what am doing wrong? Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to be overwriting `getData` in the server function.

```
library(shiny)
getData <- function(inpName) 
    if (inpName %in% names(mtcars)) mtcars[,inpName] else NULL

shinyApp(
    shinyUI(fluidPage(
        titlePanel("title"),
        sidebarLayout(
            sidebarPanel(
                textInput("name","Enter a name")),
            mainPanel(
                verbatimTextOutput('tab')
            ))
    )),
    shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
        ## The first way
        ## dat <- reactive({ getData(input$name) })

        ## The other way
        vals <- reactiveValues(dat=NULL)
        observeEvent(input$name, vals$dat <- getData(input$name))

        output$tab <- renderPrint({ summary(vals$dat) })
    })
)
```

Comment: This works! thanks! Forgive my ignorance am still new to Shiny. What am doing(getData) is extracting data from a json file based on the user name and then populate a data frame(df) with relevant details. So ideally in ShinyServer when the dat <- reactive({ getData(input$name) }) is run- it should create the required df right? It doesn't in my case. Only when the dat() is invoked in the next line does it work. Do you mind helping me understand why? Thanks again

Comment: @mongofresher it is because the reactives are functions, so they get evaluated when they are called (there is more to them, but I haven't delved into the internals of shiny).  They also have some caching mechanism that makes them smart enough to avoid re-evaluating if none of their dependencies have changed.  How that is implemented, I don't know.  Are you looking for different behaviour?  Becuase it is possible if you store the data in `reactiveValues` and update it from within an `observe`r

Comment: That makes sense! But I simply expect dat() to be evaluated.I don't need it to be displaying anything. I tried putting it in another reactive block. Doesn't work!!!!!!!

Comment: @mongofresher yea, you need to use the `reactiveValues`, I added an example

Comment: Wow! That just got more complicated (for a newbie). I wish there were more elaborate guides online on understanding reactive and reactiveValues().

Comment: Out of curiosity, once I have dat <- reactive({ getData(input$name) }) executed, isn't there a straightforward way to evaluate dat() without having to display anything on the main panel?

Comment: @mongofresher you can evaluate it in any reactive environment, it doesn't need to display anything.

Comment: Sorry, but that is the part I fail to understand. The other way example you mentioned throws a invalid 'pattern' argument error'.  The first way is easy to follow but I do not get how to evaluate dat()